# What are the 404 errors when I run update in terminal and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-terminal

What are the 404 errors when I run update in terminal and how do I get rid of them? i.e.

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

Answer (score 2):

There aren't packages in Versable PPA for trusty release, in which is based elementary OS Freya.

The last packages of elementary-update in this repository were builded to Luna, based in Precise release.

More info: [Elementary Update PPA](https://launchpad.net/~versable/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-update)